# CodeIntel2: can it be used under Py3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-intelligence

I try to run simple test py-file under Py3k, with [CodeIntel2 lib](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel). 
Package is suitable for SublimeText 2 and 3, so i guess lib is ok for Py3k.

I get this error on importing `manager.py`:

```
File "g:\_CodeIntel\serverwork.py", line 12, in <module>
  from codeintel2.manager import Manager
File "g:\_CodeIntel\libs\codeintel2\manager.py", line 287
  except CodeIntelError, ex:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can this er be fixed easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 has a slightly different format for exception handling.  Notice the `as` below:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
```

Emits:

```
division by zero
```

Comment: So Codeintel can't be fixed. easily. Crap

Comment: Not necessarily.  Did you run `2to3` on it?